# how to move multiple sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to move one sprite at a moment...but when i move sprite like this method the position of other sprite..which i does not touch its Position are interchange automatic...i have four sprite in SpriteIconArray And SameNumber Position In PointArray. Please Help Me.

```
CCLOG(@"%.f,%.f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
int k=0;
for (CCSprite *sprite in spriteIconArray)
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation))
    {
        if (k==0)
        {
            sprite.position=touchLocation;
            sprite.zOrder=INT_MAX;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            sprite.position=CGPointFromString([pointArray objectAtIndex:sprite.tag]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: the question is very difficult to interpret, try reformulating it better please.

Answer (score 0):

in.h define NSInteger SpriteTag

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in spriteIconArray)
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation))
    {
        SpriteTag=sprite.tag;
        OriginalPoint=sprite.position;
    }
}
```

}

-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in spriteIconArray)
{

    if (sprite.tag==SpriteTag)
    {
         sprite.position=touchLocation;
         sprite.zOrder=INT_MAX;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code :-

```
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

You can have 3 different textures the sprites use that is randomly assigned as the sprites are generated, so there are only 3 images applied.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg..my friend had the same kind of issue.I got the solution to use sprites in ios from this forum.I know the question is kind of unclear